# How to create unit test for a function in my case

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have something in my code like this.

```
$scope.callMe = function(test){
   ...
   myService.test(
       {'price':price, 'name':name, 'category': category, 'test': test}
   ) // category, price are complex objec
   ...
}
```

my unit test

```
it('should check the params', function(){
    spyOn(myService.test).and.callThrough();
    $scope.callMe('test1');

    expect(myService).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

I want to create a unit test to see if `myService` is called with a variable `'test1'`. I don't want to use `toHaveBeenCalledWith()` because I have to mimic bunch of complex objects and I don't want to do that. The above test won't do it. Is there a way to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mimicking a bunch of complex objects is a part of unit testing. The whole concept of fixtures is dedicated to that.

Separating data from the specs is not uncommon, it is convenient to serialize existing objects instead of creating fakes from scratch.

```
var someServiceFixture = require('./fixtures/someService.json');
...
expect(myService.test).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someServiceFixture);
```

When some arguments are positively irrelevant, fixtures can be skipped in favour of loose argument checks with :

```
expect(myService.test).toHaveBeenCalledWith({'price': jasmine.any(Object), ...);
```

In controller unit tests everything but controller should be mocked, only one unit is tested at time. This is most appropriate scenario in current spec. The controller doesn't have to satisfy stubbed service with valid arguments:

```
spyOn(myService, 'test'); // should be stubbed
$scope.price = jasmine.createSpy('price'); // should be exposed to scope to be mocked
$scope.callMe('test1');
expect(myService.test).toHaveBeenCalledWith({'price': $scope.price, ...);
```

`toHaveBeenCalledWith` performs deep equality check on objects, `{}` dummy objects comparison may be ineffective. if controller code doesn't depend on `price` type, a spy (or any other dummy function) can be used instead of object argument to make it compared strictly.